# What is the purpose of keys present in the `/etc/ssh` folder?

Tags: ssh

Using `ssh-keygen` I was able to generate a public-private key pair one Machine#1 and then I copied the public key to Machine#2 using `ssh-copy-id`. On Machine#2, I noticed that there are 3 key-pairs already generated in the `/etc/ssh` folder and I was wondering what are these for? Is the purpose of them to simply allow copying the private key and use it?

Can I grant access to Machine#1 w/o generating a key-pair by simply copying one of the private keys already present in the `/etc/ssh` folder of Machine#2? If so how do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

The keys in `/etc/ssh` are (probably) *host keys*: the keys which the client uses to verify the identify of the server to which it is connecting; not *user keys* which each user might generate to identify as an authorized user to connect to that server, and which are typically stored in `~/.ssh` for each user.  These keys are typically generated when the OpenSSH package is installed on the system, via `ssh-keygen -A` :

From the [manual page for `ssh-keygen`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#A):

> **-A**
>
> For each of the key types (rsa, dsa, ecdsa and ed25519) for which host keys do not exist, generate the host keys with the default key file path, an empty passphrase, default bits for the key type, and default comment. If **-f** has also been specified, its argument is used as a prefix to the default path for the resulting host key files. This is used by */etc/rc* to generate new host keys.

Comment: That explains it. A follow-up question: How do I, as a user, then validate if I am connecting to the right server using the server's host keys?

Comment: @Weezy, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42643/ssh-key-based-authentication-known-hosts-vs-authorized-keys

Answer (score 3):

Those are *host* keys for the server to identify itself, as their filenames imply (`ssh_host_xxx_key`). Copying them will only allow some other system to identify themselves *as the server*, they won't allow you access to the server itself.

> Can I grant access to Machine#1 w/o generating a key-pair by simply copying one of the private keys already present in the /etc/ssh folder of Machine#2? If so how do I do it?

Don't. Copying around private keys is massively insecure and should not be done.

Comment: How are we supposed to identify the correct server using the _host keys_ then?

Comment: @Weezy `ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_xxx_key.pub` will print the key fingerprint. When you first connect to an SSH server, `ssh` will print the server's fingerprint and ask you to confirm whether it is correct. Compare both.